# Google Drive API, page size of the document

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been working on Google Drive API. Is there a way to get page size of the documents?(PDF, MS Docs)

Comment: Unfortunately, the page size cannot be retrieved by Drive API. When [Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/) got to be able to be used, it might be able to be retrieved. So as a current workaround, how about creating an API for returning the page size using [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)?

Comment: Creating an API is good idea. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The google drive api is a file store api.  Its basically a directory api.  It stores the files in folders and can give you information about the files itself.

- "name": string,
- "mimeType": string,
- "description": string,

It will allow you to upload and download files to this directory.  It does not give you more information beyond that.

You cant read the contents of the file or the settings of the file in anyway with this api.